# C# Generating exception(index was outside the bounds of the array) when file ended and read no more data

Tags: c#

here's my code,what i have to do that my code stops read data when files data ended.

```
string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/"), Fileupload1.FileName);
               string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

               string[] lines = text.Split('\n');

                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                string[] Values;

                foreach (string line1 in lines)
                {
                    int a = 0;
                    Values = line1.Split(';');
                    a = a + 1;
                   // string query = "INSERT INTO cdr_info VALUES ('" + Values[0] + "'," + Values[1] + ",'" + Values[2] + "','" + Values[3] + "'," +
                    string query = "INSERT INTO cdr_info VALUES( '" + Values[0] + "', '" + Values[1] + "', '" + Values[2] + "',  '" + Values[3] + "', '" + Values[4] + "',  '" + Values[5] + "', '" + Values[6] + "',  '" + Values[7] + "',  '" + Values[8] + "', '" + Values[9] + "'," +
" '" + Values[10] + "',  '" + Values[11] + "',  '" + Values[12] + "',  '" + Values[13] + "',  '" + Values[14] + "','" + Values[15] + "', '" + Values[16] + "',  '" + Values[17] + "',  '" + Values[18] + "','" + Values[19] + "'," +
"'" + Values[20] + "','" + Values[21] + "', '" + Values[22] + "',  '" + Values[23] + "',  '" + Values[24] + "',  '" + Values[25] + "','" + Values[26] + "',  '" + Values[27] + "', '" + Values[28] + "', '" + Values[29] + "', " +
" '" + Values[30] + "', '" + Values[31] + "',  '" + Values[32] + "',  '" + Values[33] + "',  '" + Values[34] + "'," +
"'" + Values[35] + "',  '" + Values[36] + "',  '" + Values[37] + "',  '" + Values[38] + "','" + Values[39] + "', '" + Values[40] + "', '" + Values[41] + "', '" + Values[42] + "'," +
"'" + Values[43] + "', '" + Values[44] + "',  '" + Values[45] + "',  '" + Values[46] + "',  '" + Values[47] + "',  '" + Values[48] + "',  '" + Values[49] + "','" + Values[50] + "', '" + Values[51] + "'," +
" '" + Values[52] + "', '" + Values[53] + "',  '" + Values[54] + "',  '" + Values[55] + "',  '" + Values[56] + "','" + Values[57] + "', '" + Values[58] + "', '" + Values[59] + "', '" + Values[60] + "', '" + Values[61] + "'," +
"'" + Values[62] + "', '" + Values[63] + "',  '" + Values[64] + "', '" + Values[65] + "', '" + Values[66] + "','" + Values[67] + "','" + Values[68] + "','" + Values[69] + "', '" + Values[70] + "'," +
"'" + Values[71] + "', '" + Values[72] + "','" + Values[73] + "','" + Values[74] + "', '" + Values[75] + "',  '" + Values[76] + "',  '" + Values[77] + "',  '" + Values[78] + "',  '" + Values[79] + "',  '" + Values[80] + "'," +
"  '" + Values[81] + "',  '" + Values[82] + "',  '" + Values[83] + "',  '" + Values[84] + "',  '" + Values[85] + "','" + Values[86] + "', '" + Values[87] + "','" + Values[88] + "', '" + Values[89] + "',  '" + Values[90] + "'," +
"  '" + Values[91] + "',  '" + Values[92] + "', '" + Values[93] + "', '" + Values[94] + "',  '" + Values[95] + "', '" + Values[96] + "',  '" + Values[97] + "', '" + Values[98] + "',  '" + Values[99] + "',  '" + Values[100] + "'," +
"  '" + Values[101] + "',  '" + Values[102] + "',  '" + Values[103] + "'," +
" '" + Values[104] + "',  '" + Values[105] + "',  '" + Values[106] + "',  '" + Values[107] + "', '" + Values[108] + "')";
                   // string query = "INSERT INTO demooo VALUES ('" + Values[0] + "','" + Values[1] + "','" + Values[2] + "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
```

Comment: You need to go over to codereview.stackexchange.com...like immediately!

Comment: Did you ever hear of cycles? Aaand, if the file is uploaded (as it probably is), did you ever hear of SQL injection?

Comment: The error you get seems to be generated not from reading the file, but from the `Values` array length. it seems the some lines has lesser values comparing to other lines.

Comment: Parameters are your friend.

Comment: it insert all data from file to sql table but at the end generates the error.
(index was outside the bounds of the array)

Comment: @user3368644 There is something tragically wrong with your database design. Let alone how you build that query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Index was outside the bounds of the array exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868508/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-exception)

Answer (score 0):

you will get exception splitted items not having expected item count. you can add validation to avoid the exception like below

```
Values = line1.Split(';');
int itemcount = 108;
if(line1.Length >= itemcount)
{
   // your insert code 
}
```